# figure out plugin triggering autocmd that CD into home

Tags: autocmd

When I open a new file, [n]vim changes directory into home, regardless of the directory i am in.

I didn't wrote code for that behavior, so that must be a plugin. How can I figure out the origin of this? So that I can disable or tweak the plugin. There must be a way to find out what is causing vim to cd to home.

Comment: You could probably try searching your configuration for `cd`, `chdir(`, or `autocd`.

Comment: cf. [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be caused by an autocommand. You can list them all with `:autocmd` or do some filtering by looking at likely candidates such as

```
:autocmd BufNew
:autocmd BufNewFile
:autocmd BufEnter
```

Comment: thanks. I found out that it was due to a autocmd which executed "mkview and loadview" on BufWinEnter/BufWinLeave. for some reason this caused to cd into home